# Local or streamed audio using JavaScript with CefSharp or CefGlue

Tags: c#, javascript, html, audio, chromium

I've been toying with [CefSharp](https://github.com/chillitom/CefSharp) and [CefGlue](https://bitbucket.org/xilium/xilium.cefglue/wiki/Home) and managed to get CefSharp to work quite well in a C# application.

With CefSharp, I am able to execute JavaScript and load HTML from memory. For example, to execute some JavaScript, one can do this:

```
view.ExecuteScript("setInterval(function(){alert(\"Hello\")},3000);");
```

To load some HTML:

```
model.LoadHtml(string.Format("<html><body><a href='{0}'>CefSharp Home</a></body></html>", home_url));
```

I know I can load `<audio>` with some file loaded from some web server. Is there a way to load audio either from a local file or through a stream with CefGlue/Sharp?

Even better, how can this be done with "dynamic" JavaScript (for example by using `ExecuteScript(...)` above)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out. It's done by impersonating a web server. The difficulty appears to be the interpretation of what is requested, which seems to be done by parsing the requested URL. Otherwise it all works great.

```
public bool OnBeforeResourceLoad(IWebBrowser browser, 
    IRequestResponse requestResponse)
{
    IRequest request = requestResponse.Request;

    if (request.Url.EndsWith(".gif")) {
        MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        Properties.Resources.FooImage.Save(
            stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        requestResponse.RespondWith(stream, "image/gif");
    }
    else {

        Stream resourceStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
            "<html><body><img src=\"foo.gif\" /></body></html>"));
        requestResponse.RespondWith(resourceStream, "text/html");
    }

    return false;
}
```